How to I create a Mat-Step with for loop which has individual components inside?
I have around 20 forms created as difference components and implemented with mat-stepper as below
<mat-step>
    <form [formGroup]="form1">
      <component1></component1>
    </form>
    <div>
      <button  matStepperNext >Next</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>

<mat-step>
    <form [formGroup]="form1">
      <component2></component2>
    </form>
    <div>
      <button  matStepperNext >Next</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>

.
.
.
.
.
<mat-step>
    <form [formGroup]="form1">
      <component20></component20>
    </form>
    <div>
      <button matStepperNext >Next</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>

how do i create this using *ngFor?

First create an array, with each component in the TS file.
components = [
    { form: this.form1, component: Component1 },
    { form: this.form1, component: Component2 },
    { form: this.form1, component: Component3 },
    ...

    ...
    { form: this.form1, component: Component20 },
];

Then we can use ngComponentOutlet to create the component dynamically. You may need to provide an injector or a module as input, for the component to work correctly. Since no code shared on this, please go through the docs to learn more.
<mat-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="data.form" *ngFor="let data of components">
    <form [formGroup]="data.form">
       <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="data.component"></ng-container>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
</mat-stepper>


thank you Murali, the array should be String with names like "app-component1", "app-component2" etc?

@SamK It should be the actual component import.

ok and what about the [formGroup], when i put form group name it gives error and i cannot have string aswell

@SamK You can also add these as a property to the array and then configure it. like { component: Component1, form: form1 } will be a single property

When i give formgroup, i get an error Property 'form1' is used before its initialization.

@SamK updated my answer!

@SamK promote the form initialization before the property definition

thank you so much @Naren. One last question. if i want to add value to this array on a button click, how do i do it.. when i do on button click it gives me error as Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

@SamK try adding a trackBy method, also fire a change detection cycle after pushing the element, finally after pushing an element, create a new memory reference for the array using this.arr = [...this.arr];

i am novice in angular :), any code reference would help please

@SamK cehck this also last one is simple, after pushing a new element, just destructure your array using the code I provided, then trackby
